# How to save the results of Invoke-Command to a file

Tags: powershell

I read a server list from a File:

```
$servidores = Get-Content "C:\ServerList.txt"
```

for every server I execute the following command

```
foreach ($server in $servidores){
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {Select-String -Pattern "something" -Path C:\*.txt -AllMatches}
}
```

I need to store the results in a variable but can not find the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you can try this-

```
$output = @()
foreach ($server in $servidores)
{
    $singleOutput = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {Select-String -Pattern "a" -Path C:\*.txt -AllMatches}
    $output+= $singleOutput
}
$output
```